# Desktop unable to boot automatically. Need to manually select boot device everytime

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot

I have an Intel i5 2500K processor, Intel® Desktop Board DH67BL and 500GB SATA drive.

Earlier I had another hard disk with OS installed on it as well as current hard disk.
Now when I formatted the hard disk and installed linux (tried with ubuntu and fedora) I get following error on boot every time
" PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
  PXE-M05: Exiting Intel Boot Agent "

While booting if I press F10 to go to boot menu and select my hard disk manually it works fine and boots every time.

I already have my hard disk setup as boot device. I have also disabled network device boot but still am facing this issue. I tried Windows and it boots fine. But when I again install Linux as dual boot device It fails to recognize any existing partition on my hard disk and asks me to format whole drive.
Please solve.

Answer (score 1):

Something goes wrong when installing the Linux boot-loader.
It is probably in the wrong place so the bios can't find it on the first boot (causing the fall-back to LAN/PXE-boot).

The F10 forced load works (in this case) because that will probably attempt to boot from all partitions in stead of just the default one. 
(I have seen this somewhat unusual behavior before with Intel biosses.)

Make sure the boot-loader is installed in the MBR (Master boot-record) of the disk. (Most Linux distro's allow you to install it in the Linux boot-partition too but in case of a dual-boot config that is usually not a good idea.)

Updating the bios to the latest version may help as well. You never know.

Comment: @Tony, Thanks for the suggestions.
I updated the BIOS but didn't help me. Now I don't want to have dual boot but only Linux. I can format the whole hard disk as I don't have any data on it but it again needs me to force boot from hard disk using F10. Any suggestion on the installation process I should follow. I have defaulted the BIOS setting and my Hard Disk shows AHCI. And though connected to 6GB/s port on motherboard shows 3GB/s in the BIOS.